# Implementation OTP login with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot security in order to authorize the users with oAuth2, Client sends a request with username and password to `/oauth/token` and spring security handles the authentication and returns an access token and refresh token.
I want to implement OTP login as well, Client will send their phone number and back-end will be sent a confirmation code to the client with sms, and then the client will confirm the confirmation code so back-end will provide an access token and refresh token to the client.

I know the scenario, but i don't know how can I implement this ability with spring boot, All samples are for 2FA login ,I don't want to 2FA, I need a OTP without password.

Comment: I have done the similar approach, check this out https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/spring-boot-otp-login

Answer (score 1):

At a high level you will need to (as part of your registration) process - save the `mobile` number in your database / storage.  You may want to save a backup `mobile` as well (or generate backup codes e.g. 6 numbers `34932843-1234454-82034854-12948309-19459453-40048572`).  Important that the user has the ability to log in if their mobile / device doesn't work for whatever reason.

After the `username` / `password` is authenticated you generate a random OTP (6 digits is popular).  This should be stored e.g. Redis - keyed against the mobile with a TTL (time-to-live) of e.g. 1 hour). This OTP is then sent to the users mobile (e.g. using an API like https://www.twilio.com).  The user would then send that number down and that will be validated against the random number recently stored.

That's the high-level flow - in Spring boot you'd create controllers and Spring Boot security filters to implement this.  If you have a specific question on the implement sure ask and I'll add detail to this question.